# Nested each not working

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have two lists:

```
var one =["test","test1","test2"];
var two =["temp","temp1","temp2",""temp3","temp4"];
```

I tried something below but it is not working.

```
<table>
{{#each one}}
  <td>{{this}}</td>
  <td>
    <select>
     {{#each two}}
       <option>{{this}}</option>
     {{/each}}
    </select>
  </td>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the "two" array is scoped outside of the first each block.

Try this instead:

```
var context = {
 one : ["test","test1","test2"],
 two : ["temp","temp1","temp2",""temp3","temp4"]
};


<table>
{{#each context.one}}
  <td>{{this}}</td>
  <td>
    <select>
     {{#each ../two}}
       <option>{{this}}</option>
     {{/each}}
    </select>
  </td>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in second each block. It should be`{{#each two}}` instead of `{{each}}`.

Comment: Try changing {{#each two}} to {{#each ../two}}.